# Which Microservices architecture can we use to drill down a huge monolithic application that uses a no SQL DB?

Tags: java, spring, rest, architecture, microservices

We have a huge monolithic backend application built on Java-Spring that deals with the Checkout functionalities of an e-commerce retail client. The application exposes multiple REST APIs to deliver the functionalities and  uses a No SQL DB to store the data.

What type of Microservices design/architecture can we go for, if we want to break this down into granular micro services so that the code maintainability and deployments can be made much easier? Could anyone please suggest the best suitable options that we could try out?

Comment: @user1237244 https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

An incremental migration from monolith to micro-services is a safer path, you would find something called strangler pattern, which is a famous approach. Following is a good article I came across.
https://dzone.com/articles/monolith-to-microservices-using-the-strangler-patt

Firstly, you should be able to decompose your system in various aspects in terms of functionally and technically. You would need to find more information of what strategy to go forward, following research paper is a good start.
http://domainlanguage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/GettingStartedWithDDDWhenSurroundedByLegacySystemsV1.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll check that out. One other concern here is that this might require the services to use a common database. But, I guess micro services is not built for that purpose.

Comment: in an ideal situation it cannot use same database, each service should be Highly maintainable and testable, Loosely coupled, Independently deployable and
Organized around business capabilities.